# Get Array values in a loop in PHP

Tags: javascript, php, arrays, morris.js

I have an Array $data composed as following :

```
$data[$k]['id'] = $row['iddevice'];
$data[$k]['temp_00'] = $row['temp_00'];
$data[$k]['temp_01'] = $row['temp_01'];
$data[$k]['temp_02'] = $row['temp_02'];
$data[$k]['temp_03'] = $row['temp_03'];
$data[$k]['temp_04'] = $row['temp_04'];
```

I have only two elements in this Array, so `echo count($data);` return `2`

I am using Morris.js to create a line chart, below an example of working code :

```
$(function() {

    Morris.Line({
  element: 'morris-area-chart',
    data: [
  { y: '00h', 1:57, 2:41},
  { y: '01h', 1:62, 2:98},
  { y: '02h', 1:44, 2:43},
  { y: '03h', 1:67, 2:84},
  ],
  xkey: 'y',
  parseTime:false,
  ykeys: [1,2,3],
  pointSize: 2,
  hideHover: 'auto',
  labels: ['Capteur X', 'Capteur Y']
});
```

[image: Morris.js Line Chart]

My problem is as soon as I try to use PHP to use the values from my `$data` it doesn't work, the chart doesn't load any values.

```
   Morris.Line({
  element: 'morris-area-chart',
    data: [
    { y: '00h', <?php $i = 0; while ($i <= count($data)-1) { echo $data[$i]['id'].":".round($data[$i]['temp_00'],2); $i++; }?>},
    { y: '01h', <?php $i = 0; while ($i <= count($data)-1) { echo $data[$i]['id'].":".round($data[$i]['temp_01'],2); $i++; }?>},
    { y: '02h', <?php $i = 0; while ($i <= count($data)-1) { echo $data[$i]['id'].":".round($data[$i]['temp_02'],2); $i++; }?>},
    { y: '03h', <?php $i = 0; while ($i <= count($data)-1) { echo $data[$i]['id'].":".round($data[$i]['temp_03'],2); $i++; }?>},

  ],
```

For me, the algorithm is fine :

- $i equal 0
- while `$i` is lower or equal to `count($data)-1` (so 2-1 = 1 so we should stay in the loop two times)
- Display the ID and temperature values for this elements
- Increment `$i` by one

What am I thinking or doing wrong here ?

Also when I initialize `$i` to one rather than zero, I can get the values for the second entry in my `$data` Array

[image: Morris.js Chart 2]

(I prefer to say that I am not a developer so this code might not be the cleanest I agree)

**EDIT :**

- Pastebin to the `var_dump` of `$data` : http://pastebin.com/dYNtLxqX
- Screenshot when using Forbs' solution (Chart doesn't load at all) : 
  [image: Morris.js Chart 3]
- The SQL query I am using to populate `$data` Array :

  ```
  select iddevice, data.ip, type, description,
     avg(case when hour(date) = 00 then temp end) as temp_00,
     avg(case when hour(date) = 01 then temp end) as temp_01,
     avg(case when hour(date) = 02 then temp end) as temp_02,
     ...
     avg(case when hour(date) = 22 then temp end) as temp_22,
     avg(case when hour(date) = 23 then temp end) as temp_23
  from data, device
  where date >= '2017-03-20' and
    date < '2017-03-21' and
    device.ip = data.ip
  group by ip
  order by iddevice;
  ```
- The Array is populate with this query using a while loop

  ```
  $results = $conn->query($sql);
  $k = 0;
  $data = array();
  while ($row = $results->fetch_assoc()) {
      $data[$k]['temp_00'] = $row['temp_00'];
      $data[$k]['temp_01'] = $row['temp_01'];
      $data[$k]['temp_02'] = $row['temp_02'];
      $data[$k]['temp_03'] = $row['temp_03'];
      ...
      $k++;
  }
  ```

Comment: Post a `var_dump` of your `$data` var

Comment: You're using `$s` instead of `$i`, `$data[$s]['temp_00']`, maybe that is the problem.

Comment: I have updated the post; this `$i` / `$s` mistake is due to a lot of troubleshooting I have try, but it is not the problem unfortunately. I have also added a pastebin to the Array var_dump

Comment: Where is `$row` coming from? A database query? If you can add just a little more code to show a bit more of how `$row` is populated, I can show you a different way to pass the data from PHP to JS that may be easier.

Comment: I have updated the main post with the SQL query I am using to populate my `$data` array. But because I can get to the values stored in `$data` array when I do manually `echo $data[0]['id']` or `echo $data[1]['temp_00']` I don't think it is linked :/

Comment: how do you create your `$data` array ? through foreach loop ?

Comment: I am using a while loop, I have added that to the main post

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is my suggestion for a different way to do this. It cuts down on the repeated code, and minimizes the PHP/JS mixing.

First, build your array a little differently as you fetch the rows from your query:

```
while ($row = $results->fetch_assoc()) {
    // Loop over each of the temp_x columns
    for ($i=0; $i < 4; $i++) {
        $x = str_pad($i, 2, '0', STR_PAD_LEFT);
        // add the value for each temp_x to a temporary array, using time for a key
        $temp = is_null($row["temp_$x"]) ? 'null' : round($row["temp_$x"], 2);
        $times[$x][] = $row['iddevice'] . ':' . $temp;
    }
}
```

Next, format the values of each array in the temporary array

```
foreach ($times as $time => $temps) {
    $data[] = "{ y: '{$time}h', " . implode(', ', $temps) . '}';
}
```

Then convert the `$data` array to a string:

```
$data = implode(",\n", $data);
```

That way, all the PHP you'll need in the JS part is:

```
Morris.Line({
  element: 'morris-area-chart',
  data: [ <?php echo $data ?> ]
```

---

There may be a better way using `json_encode`. If you change the code inside the `while` loop that fetches rows from your database just slightly:

```
for ($i=0; $i < 4; $i++) {
    $x = str_pad($i, 2, '0', STR_PAD_LEFT);
    $temp = is_null($row["temp_$x"]) ? null : round($row["temp_$x"], 2);
    $times[$x]['y'] = $x.'h';
    $times[$x][$row['iddevice']] = $temp;
}
```

Then `$data` can be formed using `json_encode`. (The `array_values` is used to reindex the array with numeric indexes so it will render as an array in the JSON output instead of an object.)

```
$data = json_encode(array_values($times));
```

And in the JS:

```
Morris.Line({
  element: 'morris-area-chart',
  data: <?php echo $data ?>
  // note: no [] brackets around $data in this version
```

Whether or not this will work depends on whether or not it's okay for all the keys to be strings, because JSON keys are strings, so you'll get output like

```
{ "y": "01", "1": 17.62, "2": 19.52 }
```

instead of

```
{ y: '01', 1: 17.62, 2: 19.52 }
```

I think it should probably work anyway.

Comment: I wish I could give you more than one upvote ! You're a genius, thanks a lot for this solution ! Just a last thing : I have some `null` value in my db (look at the pastebin in the main post), and I would like those `null` value to be set as "null" in the morris chart and not as "0" (as it does now), that would prevent the line to go down at zero by not drawing the line at all

Comment: @William I updated the answer for that. Actually, I just realized there is a better way. I will edit again in a minute.

Comment: This new code you provide doesn't work for me : `Undefined index: id in C:\wamp64\www\project\data\data.php on line 44`. Because I have no clue how your code works I have no idea about how to get it to work on my setup x) The line 44 is the closing bracket of the for loop

Comment: I think `$times[$x][] = $row['id'] . ':' . $temp;`should be $times[$x][] = `$row['iddevice'] . ':' . $temp;` or am I wrong?

Comment: No, you're right, XerXeX. @William I updated the answer to fix that typo. I also added another possible way to do it with `json_encode`.

Comment: The chart load but there is no values using the second method so it might require to not use string as key when using morris.js (or I just did something wrong I don't know) Anyway, using your first solution it works like a charm and I can get further in my project now ! Thanks a lot for your help my savior ;)

Comment: Usually better off not constructing JSON strings manually, I would suggest `json_encode()` instead.

Comment: @JaredFarrish I agree, and I already added a part to the answer that does it that way. I just wasn't sure if it would work properly with the string keys that `json_encode` would produce instead of the integer keys used in the original code. I actually tested it after the fact and it does work, but the OP had some trouble with it for some reason.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is in the loop

```
while ($i <= count($data)-1)
```

This should be

```
while ($i <= (count($data)-1))
```

Or

```
while ($i < count($data))
```

works better

Comment: It doesn't work unfortunately; I have tried (again) all these solution and none of them did work.

Comment: What do you see when you use this data?  Can you do a copy of the final php output?  Just the morris stuff

Comment: I have edited the main post with a screenshot of the output when using your solution

Comment: That's the PHP code, I meant what the screen outputs (in Source) after you run it.

Comment: That's in, I needed a minute to put the code back as your solution was and take a screenshot then edit the post :)

Comment: sorry I mean of the code that shows up to the browser something like $(function() {

    Morris.Line({
  element: 'morris-area-chart',
    data: [
  { y: '00h', 1:57, 2:41},
  { y: '01h', 1:62, 2:98},
  { y: '02h', 1:44, 2:43},
  { y: '03h', 1:67, 2:84},
  ],

Answer (score 0):

You can optimize it even more.

```
  Morris.Line({
  element: 'morris-area-chart',
    data: [
    <?php
        foreach($data as $sensor) {
            foreach($sensor as $key => $value) {
                if($key == 'id') {
                    $id = $value;
                } else {
                    $tempTime[$key][$id] = $value;
                }
            }
        }   
        $i = 0;
        foreach($tempTime as $time) {
            echo sprintf("{ y: '%02dh', ",$i);
            foreach($time as $key => $value) {
                echo sprintf("%d:%d, ",$key, round($value,2);
            }
            echo "},";
            $i++;
        }
    ?>
  ],
  xkey: 'y',
  parseTime:false,
  ykeys: [1,2,3],
  pointSize: 2,
  hideHover: 'auto',
  labels: ['Capteur X', 'Capteur Y']
});
```

In that way, if your array gets big you won't have to repeat yourself.

Explanation
`foreach` is a function that iterates through an array.
The first foreach loop just reorders the array so that it is easy'er to use in the last `foreach` loop (you would proporly do this when you create the array from the sql in the first place, but I couldn't see how you did that from your post)
The last `foreach` loop just print out the strings needed for the `Morris.line()` function. Hope this make sense.

Comment: Do you mind to explain me how this code works ? I can get my two lines on my chart but that's not the correct values so I would like to see what is going wrong. As said, I am not a coder and I am not familiar with foreach loop at all.

Comment: I've edited the answer. What are the output? Where does it go wrong?

Comment: Thanks for your explanation. The error were about the values order I think, because some of my `null` values in the database were set at something on the chart and vice versa. It is working using Don't Panic solution anyway, but I appreciate you spent time helping me :)